# TACO CLI - failing to build on MAC (missing write access)

Tags: ios, cordova, taco

I am a broken man, my builds have been working for years, and since iOS did its latest build, i have issues. I cannot for life get this to work.

MAC is catilina, i cannot believe all of this was working and then a simple version update and i cannot get it to build. I use command line for android (it still works and build successfully). I used the gui for iOS but am now getting a vsTAC issue immediately, so changed to use TACO-cli and was able to connect to mac and start the build process. It fails with this error, my build is all there as id expect except the platform folder where id navigate to open the xcode as normal. But i assume this is because my build is failing. I have updated the mac to be on the exact versions windows is on, i have give all the files the correct permissions. I am totally at a loss. I have been on higher versions before and had it working in past, i wasnt able to update to cordova 9 as one of those plugins didnt support 9 yet.

Currently running:

- npm 6.7.0
- node 11.15.0
- cordova 8.1.2
- cordova-android 9.0.0
- cordova-ios 6.1.0

  ```
   23 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-android-permissions
   24 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-app-version
   25 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-bluetoothclassic-serial
   26 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-device
   27 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-dialogs
   28 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file
   29 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file-opener2
   30 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-file-transfer
   31 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-geolocation
   32 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
   33 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-navigationbar
   34 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-network-information
   35 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
   36 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-statusbar
   37 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-whitelist
   38 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine
   39 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr
   40 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-sqlite-storage
   41 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/es6-promise-plugin
   42 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/ionic-plugin-keyboard
   43 warn checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/uk.co.workingedge.cordova.plugin.sqliteporter
   44 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
   45 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1869ms
   46 warn VetIMPRESS@3.0.0 No repository field.
   47 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-android-permissions'
   48 verbose cwd /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp
   49 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
   50 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "cordova-plugin-vs-taco-support" "--production" "--no-save"
   51 verbose node v11.15.0
   52 verbose npm  v6.14.6
   53 error code ENOENT
   54 error syscall access
   55 error path /Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-android-permissions
   56 error errno -2
   57 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, access '/Users/AppleDev/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/3456/cordovaApp/node_modules/cordova-plugin-android-permissions'
   58 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
   59 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
  ```